# Unwrap_or_else not working for getting extension from Path

Tags: rust

I use `unwrap_or_else` for error handling. The following code wont compile:

```
use std::{path::Path, process::abort};

fn example() {
    Path::new("<path>").extension().unwrap_or_else(|err| {
        println!("{} {}", "", err);
        abort();
    });
}
```

```
error[E0593]: closure is expected to take 0 arguments, but it takes 1 argument
 --> src/lib.rs:4:37
  |
4 |     Path::new("<path>").extension().unwrap_or_else(|err| {
  |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ----- takes 1 argument
  |                                     |
  |                                     expected closure that takes 0 arguments
```

Code like this has no issues:

```
let input_file_reader = fs::File::open("<path>").unwrap_or_else(|err| {
    println!("{} {}", "", err);
    abort();
});
```

I tried to look at examples, look at `Path`, and look at general closure structure but I could not understand why `unwrap_or_else` won't work with `Path::extension` alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pub fn open<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> Result<File>;
```

```
pub fn extension(&self) -> Option<&OsStr>;
```

One returns a `Result` while the other returns an `Option`. When there's no extension it's the result is simply `None`. There is no error to pass to the callback.

```
let input_file_reader = fs::File::open("<path>").unwrap_or_else(|| ...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. so if it is option ie it only returns Some/None then only way to handle it in side the match block? Because calling unwrap would panic if there is none.